# horizontal stacked barchart v6?

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

i am trying to recreate this fiddle to v6: http://jsfiddle.net/aybalasubramanian/fp5dqaxn/

i am having problem how it got value of y0?

```
console.log('dataset 1 ', dataset)
"dataset 1 ", [[{
  x: "Aug",
  y: 123
}, {
  x: "Sep",
  y: 234
}, ...]]
stack(dataset);
console.log('dataset 2 ', dataset)
 "dataset 2 ", [[{
  x: "Aug",
  y: 123,
  y0: 0
}, {
  x: "Sep",
  y: 234,
  y0: 0
}, ... ]]
```

i am confused how did that y0 got there on dataset? i am using typescript and when i do this:

```
var dataset = dataset.map(function (group) {
 
    return group.map(function (d) {
        // Invert the x and y values, and y0 becomes x0 
        return {
            x: d.y,
            y: d.x,
            x0: d.y0
        };
    });
})
```

i get the error: Property 'y0' does not exist on type '{ y: number; x: string; }', can anyone help me convert the fiddle to v6?

Comment: I suppose y0 is a D3 byproduct of transition - you don't need it in your data

Comment: @MichaelRovinsky hello managed to work on it, can u check this out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67378754/how-to-make-rounded-corner-for-bar-lower-than-higher-bar-in-stacked-chart